# Git pull cygwin not a git-command

Tags: git, cygwin, git-svn

Hi I just installed git cygwin on my windows pc at work, but somehow git pull doesn't seems to be working.

the out put is :

git: 'pull' is not a git-command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
pull

Cant seem to figure this one out, this works fine using the msysgit version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed with a clean reinstall of cygwin. But dont know ahat caused it.

Answer (score 3):

Could you check your shell (like [this user did](http://landlessness.net/posts/view/git_index_pack_is_not_a_git_command_see_git_help_fatal_index_pack_failed/))?

```
echo $SHELL
/usr/local/anothershell
```

it should be:

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Check out also your `$PATH`

```
$ type -a git 
> git is /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/git

 export PATH=/bin:$PATH 
$ type -a git 
> git is /bin/git 
> git is /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/git
```

Note: if you have the same kind of error for `git-svn` (`git: 'svn' is not a git-command. See 'git --help'.`), make sure that ([see this blog post](http://soi.kd6.us/2008/10/07/so-i-installed-git-and-git-svn-on-cygwin/)):

- svn is installed
- Perl is installed
- you did download [`Error.pm` from CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/src/UARUN/Error-0.15/Error.pm)

Answer (score 1):

just stumbled over the same problem and it seems a recent antivirus update is to blame.

it first blocks `perl.exe` and `sh.exe` and then finally deletes them from the harddrive.

the messages are as follows (i only have a german version):

```
13.04.2010 08:37:42 C:\PROGRAMME\GIT\BIN\PERL.EXE   Der Prozess versucht, in einen anderen Prozess einzudringen. Dieses Verhalten ist charakteristisch für bestimmte Schadprogramme (Invader)
13.04.2010 08:37:42 C:\PROGRAMME\GIT\BIN\PERL.EXE   Aktion "Das Verschieben nach Quarantäne" wurde gewählt
13.04.2010 08:37:42 C:\PROGRAMME\GIT\BIN\PERL.EXE   Die ursprüngliche Datei wurde gelöscht.
…
13.04.2010 08:47:38 C:\PROGRAMME\GIT\BIN\SH.EXE Der Prozess versucht, in einen anderen Prozess einzudringen. Dieses Verhalten ist charakteristisch für bestimmte Schadprogramme (Invader)
13.04.2010 08:47:38 C:\PROGRAMME\GIT\BIN\SH.EXE Datei wurde nach Quarantäne verschoben.
13.04.2010 08:47:38 C:\PROGRAMME\GIT\BIN\SH.EXE Der Prozesse wurde zwangsläufig beendet.
```

Comment: where did these messages appear? in the console?

Comment: @MarkusPielmeier: it's almost over a year since I wrote the answer above, but if I remember correctly those messages appeared in the log file of the anti virus software

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out - apparently the newer version of git is different somehow in Cygwin.  In Windows XP I had to add 'C:\cygwin\lib\git-core' to the PATH and that fixed it right up.  Just make sure you close all bash windows before that and then restart them.

Answer (score 1):

I diden't really fix the problem with git on cygwin. My approach was to switch to [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) .